# AWS lambda deployed through webpack gives external dependencies message

Tags: amazon-web-services, webpack, aws-lambda

I am generating my bundled js file through webpack, and when I deploy this to AWS Lambda it all works fine.  I can even invoke and test it.  However on the page itself of the lambda function, I see the following warning

**This function contains external libraries. Uploading a new file will override these libraries.**

I am not sure what this means, since using webpack would have effectively bundled the whole thing into just one file.  Furthermore when I look at the s3 bucket where the function was deployed, I do not see any other file.  Does anyone know what this means?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. The AWS lambda console code editor is just for messing around and testing minor things, it can't display code with external dependencies, hence the message you're seeing. Once you begin using external libraries, you can no longer edit or see code through the console anymore.

webpack creates one ZIP file because that's what the lambda deployment API expects.  Lambda doesn't know the contents of that zip file, it just knows how to deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

It means if you're able to edit the code inline (via the Lambda console), that doing so will override the entire package.